# How do I write to a zip file in Common Lisp?

Tags: io, zip, stream, common-lisp

I'm able to open a zip entry and tweak the contents, but I can't figure out how to save them.

The [API](http://common-lisp.net/project/zip/) for CL ZIP is wanting.

Specs:

ZIP

Quicklisp

MacPorts CLISP 2.49

Aquamacs 2.1 (Emacs 23.2)

Mac OS X 10.6.4

MacBook Pro 5,1

```
; Removes newlines at the beginning of PRE tags in Sigil-edited ePub files.
;
; See http://code.google.com/p/sigil/issues/detail?id=655
;
; Andrew Pennebaker
; 16 Nov 2010

; Requires Quicklisp.
; http://www.quicklisp.org/
(ql:quickload "zip")
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")

(defvar *epub* nil)
(defvar *epub-contents* nil)
(defvar *epub-out* nil)

(defun load-epub (filename)
  (setq *epub* (zip:open-zipfile filename)))

(defun close-epub ()
  (zip:close-zipfile *epub*)
  (setq *epub* nil)
  (setq *epub-contents* nil))

(defun gather-epub-contents ()
    (zip:do-zipfile-entries (name entry *epub*)
      (push name *epub-contents*)))

(defun is-html-file (name)
  (if (cl-ppcre:scan ".+\\.htm[l]?$" name) t nil))

(defun entry-name-to-html (name)
  (flexi-streams:octets-to-string
   (zip:zipfile-entry-contents
    (zip:get-zipfile-entry name *epub*))))

(defun clean (html)
  (values
   (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all
    "<pre[^>]*>(\\s)*"
    (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "\\s+</pre>" html "</pre>")
    "<pre>")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a temp file, you're able to unzip, modify, and rezip.

See [sigil-clean.cl](https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/blob/master/common-lisp/sigil-clean.lisp)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of the Common Lisp ZIP library, you have to obtain a separate handle to write to the zip file. Probably you can extract the contents to a folder, tweak the contents and compress the whole folder with a single call to `(zip path-name source-folder)`.

Comment: Quite. But how may I read one zip and write to another (or better yet, write to the first one)?